# Updating outlook web addin in admin portal (Centralized deployment)

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-store

We have a outlook web add-in that is deployed through centralized deployment.

**Question**

1. How can i **refresh/update** the changes in manifest in admin portal. Is just clicking on "Update add-in data" button ?
2. I clicked on "Update add-in data" button but the **version of the add-in remained same**

   [image]
3. Is there an **issue with danish characters**, some characters were not displayed correctly in description.

   [image: admin portal image on danish character issue]
   [View fullsize image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2O1H.png)

Characters like **ø,å,æ** etc have issues.

Comment: Just to be sure: Have you update the `<Version>` tag?

Comment: Yes, Its updated to <Version>1.0.0.1</Version>

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify if the add-in was deployed via manifest or through the store?

Store manifest should update automatically (but can be manually refreshed via the button in red above).

If you deployed using a custom manifest, you'd need to edit your deployment and upload a new version to push an update to users.

Thanks,
Alan
Office Extensibility Team

Comment: I deployed the add-in via manifest. 

After few days i did some changes and deployed the code so i updated the version to v 1.0.0.1 in manifest and then i clicked on Update add-in button.

This should have updated the version number right ?

Comment: Hi Aditya,

Below are the steps to update an add-in that you've already deployed.

Beside the version number in the edit panel, you should be able to choose "Edit". 

 • If you are deploying via manifest, you will need to upload your newly updated manifest file.
 • If you are deploying via URL, you'll need to re-enter the URL pointing to the updated manifest. 

In either path, you will need to ensure the ID in the manifest is consistent with the old version.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the Edit link to the right of the version number it should give you an option to provide the updated manifest.

After supplying an updated manifest via file or URL it should then show an updated version number once you open the panel next time.

Comment: @Murphy , Yes the edit link does provide an option to update the version. But my question is when we click on Update add-in data , shouldn't it update the version number as well ? How will we get to know if the manifest is updated or not when we manually update the version number (via edit button) ?